# The real plane, R^2 , is a vector space over R. Describe, in geometrical terms, all subspaces of R^2

Tags: linear-algebra

The real plane, $R^2$ , is a vector space over $R$. Describe, in geometrical terms, all subspaces of $R^2$.

Can anyone help me with exercise? How can I do that in geometrical terms?

Comment: How would you describe the set 
$$
\{(x,2x):x\in\mathbb R\}
$$
geometrically?